Authenticator does not support the request and infinite loop for admin login url
Running Symfony Version

php bin/console symfony --version
Symfony 7.1.8 (env: dev, debug: true)

First let me say i know this issue has already been asked, but for older Symfony version ; and the solution provided are not matching my use case.
I'm tryig to configure 2 connections, the first one is the User connection, it's based on json and lexik_jwt and seems to be working fine. I can connect my user from my front react app to my symfony back and have a secure access to protected api url...all good.
But now i'm struggling to do what should be the easiest part; configuring an admin dashboard access from symfony itself. I've installed the EasyAdmin bundle and i'm trying to configure the access but when I try to reach my login form url, I'm getting an infinite redirection loop
[Web Server ] Dec  2 00:57:35 |INFO   | SERVER GET  (302) /admin_alz/login ip="127.0.0.1"
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point.
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Calling Authentication entry point. entry_point={"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator":[]}     
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | PHP    User Warning: Configure the "curl.cainfo", "openssl.cafile" or "openssl.capath" php.ini setting to enable the CurlHttpClient
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |INFO   | REQUES Matched route "admin_login". method="GET" request_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_alz/login" route="admin_login" route_parameters={"_controller":"App\\Controller\\Admin\\DashboardController::login","_route":"admin_login"}
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Checking for authenticator support. authenticators=1 firewall_name="admin"
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Checking support on authenticator. authenticator="Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Authenticator does not support the request.
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point.
[Application] Dec  1 23:57:35 |DEBUG  | SECURI Calling Authentication entry point. entry_point={"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator":[]}     
[Web Server ] Dec  2 00:57:35 |INFO   | SERVER GET  (302) /admin_alz/login ip="127.0.0.1"

Here is my security file
security:
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        app_admin_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin_alz
            provider: app_admin_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin_alz/login
                check_path: /admin_alz/login_check
            logout:
                path: /admin_alz/logout
            access_denied_url: /admin_alz/access-denied

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            jwt: ~

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin_alz/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/admin_alz, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

And here is my controller
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class DashboardController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/admin_alz/login', name: 'admin_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
    
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin'); 
        }
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('admin/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/admin_alz', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        if (!$this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_login');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/dashboard.html.twig');
    }

    #[Route('/admin_alz/login_check', name: 'admin_login_check')]
    public function loginCheck()
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('admin'));
    }
}

